# Hopelessly lost about lists and arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Here's the question from a practice exam I'm taking:

> Given a list, `x`, that has at least `m` elements and a list, `y`, that has at least `n` elements, write a `function` with the heading `def addThem(x, y, m, n)` that returns an array that has as it's first `m` elements the first `m` elements of `x` and as it's next `n` elements the first `n` elements of `y`.

I don't even know what an array is, let alone how to approach answering this.  My final is in the morning and I'm freaking out.  Help?

Comment: An array in this context is just another word for a list.

Comment: In this context, substitute `array` with `list` - does it make more sense in that case? As it is for an exam, you have likely covered lists and pulling out elements (`my_list[2]` or `my_list[2:5]`, for example) - can you see a way where that could apply here?

Comment: Yeah, "array" is often just used as a generic term that encompasses specific data types like Python lists. It's also used to refer to things like 2D lists of lists, but in this case, it's just another word for list.

Comment: `def addThem(x,y,m,n) : return x[:m]+y[:n]` is your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand the question, it'd be

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]

def addThem(x, y, m, n):
  return x[:m]+y[:n]
```

tell me if I do, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Wrong. This will return `None`, as `extend()` changes the list in place and returns `None`, you should try `return x[:m]+y[:n]`.

Comment: m and n need to have a set value, as list x has at least m elements and list y has at least n elements.  I think it needs to be answered with creating the addThem function then a main function to provide the values of x, y, m, and n

Comment: whoops, sorry, you're right. I didn't try it when I wrote it. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @user1751335- you would give `m` and `n` definite values at the time that you *call* the `addThem` function, but the question text you've posted doesn't say anything about that. If you're studying for a final, it might be good to look up what *function arguments* are, since that's what `m` and `n` are.

Comment: Actually this will work, and I understand it!  Thank you!

Comment: Err, the question is just to write a function with the heading def ..., it doesn't say anything about the defining the m and n. Like Marius said, you'd have to define the value of m and n by the time you call the function. You can also pass it as an argument to the function like this, addThem(x, y, 3, 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the temporary lists (only important if `m` and `n` are very large), you can do it this way

```
from itertools import chain, islice
def addThem(x, y, m, n):
    return list(chain(islice(x, 2), islice(y,2)))
```